# Undefined offset/index PHP

Tags: php, undefined

LOG:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:
```

CODE:

```
function getValueID($type) {
            $ids = $this->cfg['table']['columns']['mc_ID'];
            if ( STRLEN($ids[1]) != 1 ) {
                return $this->item[$ids[$type]];
            } else {
                $_ids = explode($ids[1], $this->item[$ids[0]]);
                return $_ids[$type];
            }
        }
        function pathImg() {
            return $this->cfg['path']['img'][0] . $this->getValueID(0) . ($this->getValueID(1) ? $this->cfg['path']['img'][1] . $this->getValueID(1) : '') . $this->cfg['path']['img'][2];
        }
```

Undefined offset: 1 in

```
if ( STRLEN($ids[1]) != 1 ) {
```

Undefined offset: 1 in

```
if ( STRLEN($ids[1]) != 1 ) {
```

Undefined index:  in

```
return $this->item[$ids[$type]];
```

Undefined offset: 2 in

```
return $this->cfg['path']['img'][0] . $this->getValueID(0) . ($this->getValueID(1) ? $this->cfg['path']['img'][1] . $this->getValueID(1) : '') . $this->cfg['path']['img'][2];
```

Comment: on which line does it occur?

Comment: `print_r($this->cfg);` to get a clue

Comment: check please...

Comment: do a `print_r($ids)` and it will help you figure out why the index on $ids does not exist.